# How to combine mutliple Vue-Concurrency errors?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm trying to use [Vue Concurrency](https://vue-concurrency.netlify.app/) with my Vue 3 / TypeScript / Quasar app.

And I am using [Quasar Notify](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/notify#introduction) to display error messages in a popup.

The notification popups are triggered like this:

```TypeScript
import { useQuasar } from 'quasar';
const $q = useQuasar();
const triggerNotification = (errorMessage: string) => {
  $q.notify(errorMessage);
};
```

And now I need a way to elegantly call `triggerNotification` whenever there is a vue-concurrency Task error.

I could do it by chaining a `catch` on the end of every `yield` statement in every Task.

But my code has many Tasks each with many `yield` statements. Chaining `catch` to each one looks messy and verbose.

Is there a better way to trigger the `triggerNotification` function for every task?

To illustrate the problem here is some example code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useTask, timeout } from 'vue-concurrency';
import { useQuasar } from 'quasar';
const $q = useQuasar();
const triggerNotification = (errorMessage: string) => {
  $q.notify(errorMessage);
};
const exampleAsyncWithError = async () => {
  await timeout(1);
  throw new Error('Ruh oh! Error.');
};
const example1Task = useTask(function* () {
  yield throwError().catch((err) => {
    triggerNotification(err.message);
  });
  yield throwError().catch((err) => {
    triggerNotification(err.message);
  });
  yield throwError().catch((err) => {
    triggerNotification(err.message);
  });
});
const example2Task = useTask(function* () {
  yield throwError().catch((err) => {
    triggerNotification(err.message);
  });
  yield throwError().catch((err) => {
    triggerNotification(err.message);
  });
  yield throwError().catch((err) => {
    triggerNotification(err.message);
  });
});
const example3Task = useTask(function* () {
  yield throwError().catch((err) => {
    triggerNotification(err.message);
  });
  yield throwError().catch((err) => {
    triggerNotification(err.message);
  });
  yield throwError().catch((err) => {
    triggerNotification(err.message);
  });
});
</script>

<template>
  <q-btn label="Run Task" @click="example1Task.perform">
  <q-btn label="Run Task" @click="example2Task.perform">
  <q-btn label="Run Task" @click="example3Task.perform">
</q-btn>
</template>
```

I also tired implementing a `useTaskGroup` and with a single `catch` on the end of that. But it doesn't work because `useTaskGroup` is not "thenable".

Maybe there is another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below text is copied from this [very helpful answer on Github](https://github.com/MartinMalinda/vue-concurrency/issues/76), made by the creator of Vue Concurrency:

I think this depends on how you want to handle the errors. I sometimes use these popup notifications as well - they're good for cases when there's no relevant place to display the error, and especially if something breaks in the background.

So my workflow usally is 90% times - display error "in place" and use `task.last.error`. In the rest cases I do `try catch` inside the task and use something like your `triggerNotification`.

Buf if you plan to use triggerNotification a lot, it's indeed maybe not optimal to do so many try catch.

What you can do is wrap the entire task perform in a try catch.

```TypeScript
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useTask, timeout } from 'vue-concurrency';
import { useQuasar } from 'quasar';
const $q = useQuasar();
const throwError = async () => {
  await timeout(1);
  throw new Error('Ruh oh! Error.');
};
const exampleTask = useTask(function* () {
  yield throwError().catch((err) => {
    triggerNotification(err.message);
  });
});

const save = async () => {
  try {
   await exampleTask.perform();
  } catch (e) {
    $q.notify(error.message);
}
};
</script>

<template>
  <q-btn label="Run Task" @click="save"></q-btn>
</template>
```

You'd be creating these wrapper functions a lot, so you can write some higher order function for it:

```TypeScript
const performAndNotify = async (task, ...args) => {
  try {
  await task.perform(...args);
 } catch (error) {
  $q.notify(error.message);
 }
};
```

Then you can reuse this function at multiple places.